# Error in object generation to logic gates simulator in p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, p5.js

in my logic gates simulator I am doing another object to generate to the canvas and I am doing a frequency generator but when I have the onclick function on the button so that it is generated, my frequency does not work and the whole object does not work. Someone would advise me thank you.

**The link to the whole project is here in the online p5.js editor:** https://editor.p5js.org/jakubmitrega1/sketches/Mg1BGpimz

**Entity generation functions:**

```
 function createEntity(type) {
  if (type === "switch") {
    entities.push(new Switch(100, 100));
    console.log("Vytvořil si switch!")
  } else if (type === "light") {
    entities.push(new Light(100, 200));
    console.log("Vytvořil si light!")
  } else if (type === "generator") {
    entities.push(new Generator(100, 300));
    console.log("Vytvořil si light!")
  }
}
```

**Generator code:**

```
class Generator extends Entity {
    constructor (x, y, frequency) {
        super(x, y, 32, 32);

        this.frequency = frequency;

        this.state = 0;
        this.output = new Pin(x, y, OUTPUT);
    }
    draw() {
        
        this.output.pos.x = this.pos.x+32;
        this.output.pos.y = this.pos.y;
        this.output.draw();
        
        this.state = millis()%(2000/this.frequency)<(1000/this.frequency) ? 1 : 0;

        push();
        translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);

        if (this.mouseOver()) {
            stroke('white');
        } else {
            noStroke();
        }

        fill('#888');
        rectMode(CENTER);
        rect(0, 0, 32, 32);

        noStroke();

        fill(255);
        textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
        textSize(24);
        text(this.state, 0, 0);
        
        textSize(12);
        textAlign(CENTER, TOP);
        text('Freq: ' + this.frequency + ' hz', 0, 20);

        pop();
    }
    
    mousePressed() {
        this.output.mousePressed();
    }
    mouseReleased() {
        this.output.mouseReleased();
    }
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<body>
        <div class="menu">
            <button onclick="switchMode('hand')">Hand <i class="far fa-hand-paper"></i></button>
            <button onclick="switchMode('move')">Move <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i></button>
            <button onclick="switchMode('wire')">Wire <i class="fas fa-plug"></i></button>
            <button onclick="switchMode('jsonexport')">JSON export <i class="fas fa-file-export"></i></button>
            <button onclick="createEntity('switch')">Switch</button>
            <button onclick="createEntity('light')">Light</button>
            <button onclick="createEntity('generator')">Generator</button>
        </div>

        <br>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line :

```
entities.push(new Generator(100, 300));
```

you don't pass the frequency to the generator

```
entities.push(new Generator(100, 300, 10));
```

should work?

Comment: resolved thank you for your help